# Extra data in a for loop

Tags: swift, for-loop, textures

I'm trying to do a for loop to append some data to another array. I only have 5 items in my folder but it gives me 6 items instead. I'm not sure what to do on my for loop.

[image]

and my code is this:

```
// TextureAtlas been populated by the Images folder
    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "RockImages")

    // Adds the images from the textureAtlas to the textureArray in order
    for i in 0...textureAtlas.textureNames.count {
        let Name = "rock_\(i).png"
        textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
    }
```

This is what I get when I print out textureArray:

[image]

Comment: The `for` line should be `for i in 0..<textureAtlas.textureNames.count`. It's `..<` instead of `...`

Comment: ... or, alternatively, `for i in 1...textureAtlas.textureNames.count` for `rock_1.png` through `rock_5.png` (as compared to `rock_0.png` through `rock_4.png`). Also, voting to close this one as ~small typographical error.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. I knew it had to be something dumb like that lol.

Comment: And not to forget:  `for name in textureAtlas.textureNames`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solving the immediate problem

This is why you shouldn't manually write the index range.

```
for i in 0...textureAtlas.textureNames.count
```

should be

```
for i in 0..<textureAtlas.textureNames.count
```

The potential for this error to occur would be completely avoided if you just used

```
for i in textureAtlas.textureNames.indices
```

### But there's a better way

You already have the texture names available to you. There's no need to get the indices, and manually convert them into names with `let name = "rock_\(i).png"`. Just do:

```
for name in textureAtlas.textureNames {
    textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
}
```

### But wait, there's more!

You should avoid this pattern of creating an empty array, and repeatedly adding elements to it. It's a lot of boilerplate code, it's slow, and it requires your array to be mutable, even if it otherwise wouldn't need to be. Use [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688519-map) instead.

```
let textureArray = textureAtlas.textureNames.map(SKTexture.init(imageNamed:))
```

Comment: That was awesome :) Thank you.